# Installing from Local Dependencies?

Tags: installation, package-management, dependencies, deb

I have a folder with all dependencies needed for my program (gimp) in a folder. I don't have internet connection on that System.

How can i install Gimp Dependencies from that Folder.

Note:
All Dependencies are in same folder as gimp.deb . But every time i try to `dpk -i gimp.deb` it throws me some error on Dependencies not met.

How can i tell the `dpkg` to search for dependencies in my own folder.

Answer (score 1):

dpkg makes this easy.

`sudo dpkg -i -R directoryname`

Where *directoryname* is the directory where you have stored all the dependencies will `-i` install `-R` recursively. You may wish to move the gimp.deb out of that directory and install it separately once you've successfully installed all the dependencies.

Other methods include [writing a script](https://askubuntu.com/a/39547/225694) to loop through the packages in the directory and [creating a package list](https://askubuntu.com/a/39570/225694) to install from but I don't believe these are necessary.

Sources:

`man dpkg`

http://www.tecmint.com/dpkg-command-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not enough to have the dependencies in a folder. The debian packaging system Ubuntu uses requires the dependencies to be installed in the system. Each installed package is added to a database.

A possible advantage of this is that the dependencies' programs and other files will be copied to the directories that are part of the system's various search paths so other programs you install later will be able to use them too.

If you have to install the debs manually you can examine them first with the archive manager (just right click the deb's in your GUI and you should see it). Look at the DEBIAN/control file to see what dependencies it has. Then you can try to install just the dependencies you need. If you get an error message about dependencies when you are installing a dependency you may need to recurse.

Gimp is so complex that you may have to take your system somewhere that has an Internet connection, unfortunately. Gimp spawned the toolkit library gtk that is used all across gnome GUI programs (many, many Ubuntu GUI programs). Fortunately, all the basic ones should already be part of your system if you are working on an Ubuntu desktop system.

Comment: But how do i install dependencies from Directory? If dependencies are in Director and i don't have internet to download them again.

Comment: If they are already packaged up as package.deb you can install them with `dpkg -i package`. If not, I'm afraid you will have to use an Internet connected computer to grab them and transport them to your computer. You might also be able to package them up yourself, but that's quite a job.

Comment: They are packaged, but its lots of work , to manually do this for all of them. I have lots of .deb . I can't install all, coz some can break my system. I only need those that i need for a specific package.

Comment: I've added some information to the question to tell you which ones you need. Gimp is a huge package. this may not be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: dpkg does what the OP is asking for. See my answer.